# Cocos2d Admob Integration - Click on the banner doesn't show full view

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, admob

I am trying to integrate AdMob into my cocos2d Game and I having some problems. Basically the ad shows up but when I click on it, the banner disappears and the full view doesn't show up. I am using a slight modified version of the code found on google admob page. Here is my code:

```
-(void) addAdMobBanner{
NSLog(@"adding Admob");
controller = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height);
// Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width/2+50,
size.height-GAD_SIZE_468x60.height,
GAD_SIZE_468x60.width,
GAD_SIZE_468x60.height)];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView.adUnitID = @"xxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView.rootViewController = controller;

[controller.view addSubview:bannerView];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]addSubview : controller.view];
[bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Tell me what CCLOG(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(size)) outputs, both before you modify the size later.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on a simulator but it works on the device, but if you are using in the landscape mode you have to transform it yourselves.